# What is the T-SQL code to grant VIEW definitions excluding Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view, permissions

Is it possible to grant VIEW DEFINITION to a user but exclude access (viewing) of Stored Procedures on a database? Is it possible? If yes, what is the correct syntax to do so?

I am aware of the following T-SQL syntax:

```
USE MyDatabase
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [user1]
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a procedure for doing this.I made some small edit to the code which is available [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1593/granting-view-definition-permission-to-a-user-or-role-in-sql-server/).

***Procedure:***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ExecGrantViewDefinition  
(@login VARCHAR(30))  
AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON  

CREATE TABLE #runSQL 
(runSQL VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL)  

DECLARE @execSQL VARCHAR(2000), @space CHAR (1), @TO CHAR (2)  

SET @to = 'TO' 
SET @execSQL = 'Grant View Definition ON '  
SET @login = REPLACE(REPLACE (@login, '[', ''), ']', '') 
SET @login = '[' + @login + ']' 
SET @space = ' ' 

INSERT INTO #runSQL  
SELECT @execSQL + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + [name] + @space + @TO + @space + @login  
FROM sys.all_objects s  
WHERE type IN ('V', 'FN', 'TR', 'IF', 'TF', 'U') --include all objects other than procedures 
AND is_ms_shipped = 0  
ORDER BY s.type, s.name  

SET @execSQL = ''  

Execute_SQL:  

SET ROWCOUNT 1  

SELECT @execSQL = runSQL FROM #runSQL 

EXEC (@execSQL) 

DELETE FROM #runSQL WHERE runSQL = @execSQL 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #runSQL)  
   GOTO Execute_SQL  

SET ROWCOUNT 0 

DROP TABLE #runSQL  

GO
```

You can pass the `user` as parameter to this procedure.

```
EXEC usp_ExecGrantViewDefinition 'user1' 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way(not tested)

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)= ''

SET @sql = (SELECT ' GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON '
                   + Schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + Quotename(name)
                   + ' TO ' + '[user_name] ;'
            FROM  sys.all_objects s  
            WHERE type IN ('V', 'FN', 'TR', 'IF', 'TF', 'U')  
            AND is_ms_shipped = 0  
            FOR xml path(''))

SELECT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I think NOT IN  clause is not required.Also need to remove 'P' from IN clause?

Answer (score 0):

You can grant `view definition` on the database level, like you do, and then deny it for stored procedures. In SQL Server, `deny` always overrides `grant` on the same level.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help with the T-SQL syntax for the DENY part?

Answer (score 0):

**Unnikrishnan R** thank for your answer.
I made some modifications. I use type 'P' - store procedure, and I do it without temp table.
I tried it at MS SQL Server 2012 and it works.

```
DECLARE @runSQL TABLE(sqlCommand VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL)

DECLARE @execSQL VARCHAR(2000), @space CHAR (1), @TO CHAR (2)  
DECLARE @login NVARCHAR(20) = 'name'

SET @to = 'TO' 
SET @execSQL = 'Grant View Definition ON '  
SET @login = REPLACE(REPLACE (@login, '[', ''), ']', '') 
SET @login = '[' + @login + ']' 
SET @space = ' '

INSERT INTO @runSQL
SELECT (@execSQL + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + [name] + @space + @TO + @space + @login) AS sqlCommand
FROM sys.all_objects s  
WHERE type IN ('P') 
AND is_ms_shipped = 0   AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)= 'dbo'
AND s.name NOT LIKE 'sys%' AND s.name NOT LIKE 'sp%'
ORDER BY s.type, s.name  

SET @execSQL = ''  
SELECT @execSQL = @execSQL+ sqlCommand + ' ' FROM @runSQL 

EXEC (@execSQL)
```